# How to add product tags in magento 1.9 from frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tags

I was trying to add product tags from frontend ,it is not working or its disabled,

Anybody have an idea of why taging is disabled in front end ?

Although i can add tags from the backend .

screenshot given below .

[image]

Comment: You might want to add if this installation is completely standard or not. The theme looks like a default one but could be adapted ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the RWD theme which does not include Product Tags by default. Here's how to add them to the RWD theme:

**Step 1:**

- Copy the tags template files to your theme
- Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag`
- Copy the entire `/tag` folder to:
  -`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template`

**Note that you may have a custom package instead of 'rwd' and you should have a custom theme name instead of 'default'**

**Step 2:**

- Add the XML call to your layout
  open `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/tag.xml` change the following code from:

> ```
> <!-- Remove all tags functionality from theme layout -->
> ```

to:

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
     <label>Catalog Product View</label>
      <!-- Mage_Tag -->
     <reference name="product.info.additional">
         <block type="tag/product_list" name="product_tag_list" before="-" template="tag/list.phtml">
             <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.tag.list.list.before" as="list_before"
 translate="label">
                 <label>Tags List Before</label>
                 <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
             </block>
         </block>
     </reference> 
  </catalog_product_view>
```

**Note that you may have a custom package instead of 'rwd' and you should have a custom theme name instead of 'default'**

If you don't know which package/theme you are using you can check in the admin under `System->Configuration->Design(left column)->Package(tab) & Theme(tab)`.

You may need to flush you Magento caches to see the changes. In the admin go to `System->Cache Management` and flush all Magento caches. Now refresh your website and you should see the tags show up near the bottom of the page below the Upsell Products.

Comment: Thanks , it worked , a doubt is that why some modules disabled in rwd theme ??

Comment: And how to enable popular tags as a block as like in magento 1.7

Comment: Enabling Popular tags would be a separate question, you'll want to post that in its own question.

Comment: Okay i posted the question

Comment: The question got flagged for being unclear.  I understand it but that could be because of answering this question.  The solution to adding the Popular Tags to the left column is this:

1. make sure you have products that have been 'tagged' you can submit this via the website as a customer or through the admin as an admin (Catalog -> Tags -> All Tags -> Add New Tag if you do not already have some, if you do then click on the tag and add it to a few products).

Comment: 2. 
Inside the same local.xml file add the following block of code, be sure to add it between the <layout> and </layout>
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Tag -->
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </default>